# How can you get the PHP code to render 4x4 grid layout for my products?

Tags: php, html, css

//Also how can I achieve a 4x4 grid view of my products without using a table? thanks in advance.

```
<?php
include"storescripts/connect_to_mysql.php";
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY date_added DESC LIMIT 15");
$columncount = 0;
$dynamicList = '<table align="center" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="6"><tr>';



    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
        $id=$row["id"];
        $product_image = $row["product_image"];
        $product_name = $row["product_name"];
        $price=$row["price"];
        $date_added = strftime("&b &d, &y", strtotime($row["date_added"]));




 $dynamicList .= '<td width="135"><a href="product.php?id=' . $id . '">
      <img src="inventory_images' . $id . '.jpg" alt="" width="129" height="169" border="0">
    </a>
  </td>

  <td width="593" valign="bottom"></br>' . $product_name . '<br>
  £' . $price . '<br>
  <a href="product.php?id=' . $id . '">View Product Details</a></td>';
```

//The missing table tag is causes my footer to go up above the product list. thats why I have left it out

```
if($columncount == 3)
{
 $dynamicList .= '</tr>';
 $columncount = 0;
}   
 else
{
  $columncount++; 
 }
}
mysql_close();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is more about HTML and CSS than about PHP. But a grid without using a HTML table you could do like this:

```
echo '<div class="items">' , PHP_EOL , PHP_EOL;

$itemCount = 0;

while($itemCount < 16){
    $rowOpeningHtml = null;
    $rowClosingHtml = null;

    if($itemCount%4 === 0) {
        $rowOpeningHtml = '<div class="item-row">' . PHP_EOL;

        if($itemCount > 0)
            $rowClosingHtml = '</div>' . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
    }

    echo $rowClosingHtml , $rowOpeningHtml , "\t" ,  '<div class="item">item' , ($itemCount + 1) , '</div>' , PHP_EOL; 

    ++$itemCount;
}

echo '</div>' , PHP_EOL , PHP_EOL , '</div>';
```

And style it with some fancy CSS.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I have applied what you said and added some css styling to it but now it gives me 8 in a row rather than the 4 I want.  Also what does this  $rowClosingHtml variable do? I am new to php so a little rusty.

Comment: @wazza Sorry made a mistake which generated wrong HTML. Try out my updated answer.

Comment: Hiya, I tried that updated code you send still playing up. it give me more pics in a row than needed. also when I echo it out in my content area, it interfere with my footer. :(

Comment: It does work for me with this minimal CSS `.item { float: left; width: 25%; }`. If this conflicts with your footer. Use a clearfix CSS class additional to the `items` class in the first `<div>`